# Can't Convert byte[] to Binary in Linq

Tags: linq, observablecollection

I am working on Linq Query through the ObservableCollection, but I am not able to convert type binary to byte[].

my code is like this.

```
q1 = (from a in Helper.db.AccountStatement
                      join b in Helper.db.BankAccount on a.BankAccId equals b.BankAccId
                      join c in Helper.db.BankBranch on b.BankBranchId equals c.BankBranchId
                      join d in Helper.db.Bank on c.BankId equals d.BankId
                      where b.AccType == stracctype && b.UserId == intuserid && a.ActiveStatement == true && b.ActiveAccount == true
                      group new { b, d, a } by new { b.BankAccId, d.Name, b.AccNumber } into h
                      select new BankSummaryDataGrid
                      {
                          BankAccId = h.Key.BankAccId,
                          byteLogo = Convert.FromBase64String(d.VectorLogo.ToString().Replace("\"", "")),
                          BankName = h.Key.Name,
                          AccountNumber = h.Key.AccNumber,
                          ClosingBalance = ((h.Where(p => p.a.TxtType == HMBL.WealthManager.WMCoAEntities.clsTransactionType.strDr).Sum(p => p.a.TxnAmt) == null ? 0.0 : h.Where(p => p.a.TxtType == HMBL.WealthManager.WMCoAEntities.clsTransactionType.strDr).Sum(p => p.a.TxnAmt)) - (h.Where(p => p.a.TxtType == HMBL.WealthManager.WMCoAEntities.clsTransactionType.strCr).Sum(p => p.a.TxnAmt) == null ? 0.0 : h.Where(p => p.a.TxtType == HMBL.WealthManager.WMCoAEntities.clsTransactionType.strCr).Sum(p => p.a.TxnAmt)))
                      }).ToList();
```

BankSummaryDataGrid is the Class of ObservableCollection. so the I am getting error like this.

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 19,Token line offset = 41,Token in error = MAX ]

byteLogo is the type of the byte[].!

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException was caught
>     Message=There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 19,Token line offset = 41,Token in error = MAX ]
>     Source=SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
>     HResult=-2147217900
>     NativeError=25501
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()
>          at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)
>          at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
>          at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
>          at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
>          at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
>          at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
>          at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at HMBL.Bank.GetBankSummary(Int32 intuserid, String stracctype) in E:\Working Folder 2011\MoneyCubePlus\Source\HMBL\TransactionManager\Transaction.cs:line 993
>     InnerException:

Thanks...!!

Comment: Have you profiled the database to see what the generated SQL looks like? Can you post it?

Comment: Yes Dear Xhalent, I had added the complete error log.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you are using methods that are not supported by linq to sql

I would change this

```
byteLogo = Convert.FromBase64String(d.VectorLogo.ToString().Replace("\"", "")),
```

To

```
vectorLogo= d.VectorLogo
```

And then once you have the list locally I would convert it to your byte array with linq to objects

Comment: See this wbould be the my query result as abve you describe. I want to convet binary to byte[] I am using FromBase64String this is not supported in Lnq. that is I know so is there any alternate way  to solve it thanks.

Comment: @Jitendra I suggested that you convert it to a byte[] after you execute the linq statement, not inside the linq statement